# how to run python code in atom in a terminal?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, atom-editor

I'm a beginner in programming and atom so when try to run my python code written in the atom in terminal I don't know how...i tried installing packages like run-in-terminal,platformio-ide-terminal but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Try `$python3 name_of_your_file.py` in the appropriate directory

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your Script as a **.py** file in a directory.
2. Open the terminal and navigate to the directory containing your script using **cd** command.
3. Run `python <filename>.py` if you are using python2
4. Run `python3 <filename.py>` if you are using python3

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to do it using extensions. I would use the platformio-ide-terminal and just do it from the command line.

Just type: Python script_name.py and it should run fine.  Be sure you are in the same directory as your python script.

Answer (score 0):

"python filename.py" should run your python code. If you wish to specifically run the program using python 3.6 then it would be "python3.6 filename.py".